# MigraDoc - How to remove top margin?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm very new to PDF generate from C#, and I'm using MigraDoc. I tried to set margin to 0 already but it seems margin still exist.

Here is code

```
Document document = new Document();
document.DefaultPageSetup.TopMargin = 0;

Section section = document.AddSection();

section.PageSetup.PageWidth = "21.7cm";
section.PageSetup.PageHeight = "9cm";
section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "0cm";
section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = "0cm";
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image image2 = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage("D:\\output\\sky-690293_640.jpg");
image2.Height = "9cm";
image2.LockAspectRatio = true;
image2.Top = 0;
image2.Left = 0;
image2.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

But still, there is a margin on the top.

[Top margin still exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YXXk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the image to the header - and TopMargin is not relevant for the contents of the header.

Either add the image to the document body and TopMargin will apply - or set the HeaderDistance property of the PageSetup.

And BTW: Never modify the DefaultPageSetup as you do in the second line of code.

Update: You can place images at an absolute position - in your case that would be (0, 0). This will work for images in the header as well as for images in the body and independent of the margin setting.

Untested code to get you started if you want to try absolute positioning:

```
image2.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
image2.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
image2.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```